# AWS Elastic Inference with Pytorch-EIA 1.3.1 results Segmentation Fault

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services

I'm deploying Elastic Inference on our AWS server.

There are some model that i have to convert to TorchScript module to use with Elastic Inference.

But when I'm converting the models, python result Segmentation fault error without any explanation.

I searched and enable the debug function, then it result Segmentation fault error with info (the info lead me to the torch-eia (provided by AWS) source code)

I keep searching and change the system recursion limit value, expand the stach_size value, and the error is a bit different. Instead of Segmentation fault, it now result Segmentation fault (core dump)

The RAM and CPU is good, stack_size has been increased, recursion limit increased too.

[This is error message screen shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9x2T.png)

[And this is error message when I debug with ubuntu gdb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFy80.png)
Please helps, I appreciate your helps. Thank you.

I'm runing with python 3.6
torch-eia 1.3.1 support Elastic Inference

Comment: Anyone here? please help.

Comment: The problem was:

Because the TorchScript does not support ModuleList indexing as well as zipping, I have used nested looping to overcome this.

But the nested looping of 2 (or more) ModuleLists will result Segmentation Fault error.

We cannot understand the error message, Segmentation Fault is hardward error but in this case it is about nested looping over many ModuleLists. 

Of course, I don't think this is the only cause of Segmentation Fault error, but when you are deploying Elastic Inference, it is worth to try.